# Object with multiple properties

Tags: javascript, object

I want to return an object with key the date, and 2 properties: margin and consultant.

```
!(moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY') in this.grossMargin) ?
  this.grossMargin[moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY')] = timesheet.invoice.total - timesheet.purchase.total :
  this.grossMargin[moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY')] += timesheet.invoice.total - timesheet.purchase.total
```

this.grossMargin returns an object with year as key and grossMargin as value. Now I want to add another element in the object like the total of the consultant.

I tried this but this doesn't work:

```
if (!(moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY') in this.grossMargin)) {
  this.grossMargin[moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY')].margin = timesheet.invoice.total - timesheet.purchase.total
  this.grossMargin[moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY')].consultant = consultant.invoice.total - consultant.purchase.total
} else {
  this.grossMargin[moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY')].margin += timesheet.invoice.total - timesheet.purchase.total
  this.grossMargin[moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY')].consultant += consultant.invoice.total - consultant.purchase.total
}
```

Error:  Cannot set property 'margin' of undefined

Comment: "this doesn't work:" is not enough. What is the current output and what is the expected output?

Comment: @enzo what is your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first define this.grossMargin['2018'] (for example).

```
if (!(moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY') in this.grossMargin)) {
  this.grossMargin[moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY')] = {};
  this.grossMargin[moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY')].margin = timesheet.invoice.total - timesheet.purchase.total
  this.grossMargin[moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY')].consultant = consultant.invoice.total - consultant.purchase.total
} else {
  // here this.grossMargin[moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY')] is defined, 
  // but you need to make sure it's an object first
  this.grossMargin[moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY')].margin += timesheet.invoice.total - timesheet.purchase.total
  this.grossMargin[moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY')].consultant += consultant.invoice.total - consultant.purchase.total
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take this part of the code

```
if (!(moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY') in this.grossMargin))
```

Ok, let's call moment(timesheet.date).format('YYYY')  the key. You're checking if !(key in this.grossMargin) then you try to set the margin for an undefined object, by doing this.grossMargin[key].margin. If you want to initialize the object you 
should do

```
this.grossMargin[key] = { 
  margin: value, 
  consultant: value 
}
```